# Echarts - custom toolbox feature mark / comment

Tags: javascript, echarts

I'm trying to create a custom toolbox feature in echarts 3.8.5, so the user can add marks or comments to the chart. I didn't find any demo with custom features, and documentation to Extension API is missing.

My questions:

1. How to set custom feature as "active" when user clicks on it (e.g., like when you select brush in predefined features)
2. How can I get coords of user click in chart
3. How to add custom element to chart

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. **How to set custom feature as "active" when user clicks on it (e.g., like when you select brush in predefined features)**

   - You can either [dispatch an action](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/api.html#echartsInstance.dispatchAction),
   - Or you can manually change the chart object and overwrite/replace the existing chart object. You can use [chart.setOption()](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption) to insert a completely new chart object **
2. **How can I get coords of user click in chart**

   - [Use mouse events](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/api.html#events.Mouse%20events) to capture clicks, hovers, etc.
3. **How to add custom element to chart**

   - For adding something (axis, series, ..) to options, you can use [chart.setOption()](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption).
   - For toggling settings or triggering actions such as datazoom, you can [dispatch an action](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/api.html#echartsInstance.dispatchAction).

---

** When you have a [custom toolbox feature](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#toolbox.feature) (note: it must always start with *my*):

```
toolbox: {
    feature: {
        myFeature: {
            show: true,
            title: 'My custom feature',
            icon: 'image:path/to/image-inactive.png'
            onclick: function (){
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
},
```

You can manually update the icon to an active state by using:

```
chart.setOption({
    toolbox: {
        feature: {
            myFeature: {
                icon: 'image:path/to/image-active.png'
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Echarts will detect the changes, and updates the icon. Of course, you can set it back to *inactive* with the same logic.

Comment: Can you be more specific with 1) please? I've read documentation to all actions but I still don't know which one to use and how. When I click on custom feature in toolbox, I want this feature to be visibly active so I'm not sure if I should use highlight or toolbox action

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I've tried to come up with a solution. Can you try this? I think this should work.

Comment: How to call another function in react once toolbox custom feature is clicked

Comment: @CyberAbhay I've never used react, but you can probably bind something to the `onclick()` handler. But how, I don't know..

Comment: Yes i did the same but inside onclick i can access this . here inside onclick this is for chart not for component/class. so calling function in class is issue for me